# How to do server call even when the app is killed and show localnotification in ios.

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

How to do server call even when the app is killed and show localnotification in ios. Right now am running timer in didUpdateLocations. It works fine when app is in background,but not when app is killed. 
Please let me know is it possible to do and if yes how?

Comment: Timers won't continue to execute indefinitely  in the background; the behaviour is different when your app is running under the Xcode debugger. If you try without debugger you will find your app is killed after a couple of minutes You can't do anything when the app is terminated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You may get the behavior you want using push notifications.

Answer (score 2):

This not possible using the `UILocalNotification`. Please refer the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) document For `UILoccalNotification`.

Lets get some understanding about the `UILoccalNotification`.

- No method call when the you have received Local Notification.
- `didReceiveLocalNotification` method call when user tap the notification in terminate state.

**So basically you can not use UILocalnotification for update location in Terminate state. You cannot do anything once your app has been terminated using local notification**

Comment: You should add; "You cannot do anything once your app has been terminated"